# How to allow numbering of white pages in memoir class?

Tags: latex, page-numbering, memoir

I have this kind of document

`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}`

however, the left blank pages due to the openright option are not numbered. For example, I am moving from page 5 to 7 since the page 6 is actually empty. How is it possible to let the page number appear on blank even pages ?

In other words, I want every page of my document to be numbered even if it is blank page

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `\pagestyle{plain}` before `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\newpage

\blindtext

\newpage

\blindtext

\end{document}
```